# What can be happening with the partition of my cube?

Tags: ssms, olap-cube, ssas-tabular

I've been having an error after I added some partitions (year related) to my cube. I added the partitions on partition manager at SSAS (Visual Studio) and then copied the final code of the cube and created it in SSMS. I dont even have data there yet but I am already experiencing errors in the fact table. There are some specific METRICS that is giving me an error after adding the partitions but it doesnt even say what. Have you guys ever experienced something like this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try deploying it from VS? does it have the same issue?

Comment: I found the problem!! And I already tried that. The problem was I was executing the xml code in the 2017 version of SSMS. When I did that in the 2018 version I didnt get any errors and the cube works fine (I couldnt believe the problem was the version I was executing the code -_-). Thank you for replying!!